# How do i add a column indicating label is unique

Tags: r

I have the following

```
df <- iris
df$label = paste(df$Species,df$Petal.Length) # Previously I was using all the fields, hence the answer using Duplicated.
```

Next I want to flag the records that have a unique label
In psuedo code

```
df$LabelIsUnique <- Count of Label = 1
```

How do I do that?
My motivation is to exclude the unique labels from analysis

[Update]
Trying akrun's solution
[image: mutate]

If I try the second option with

```
i1 <- do.call(paste, df)
df$LabelIsUnique <- match(i1, unique(i1))
head(df)
```

I see the LabelIsUnique column acting like a row number not a flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R you could use `duplicated`

```
transform(iris, LabelisUnique = + !(duplicated(iris)|duplicated(iris, fromLast = TRUE)))
```

Comment: `df$label %in% df$label[duplicated(df$label)]` as a variation

Comment: In your answer, how does duplicated "know" to use label column?

Comment: @KirstenGreed In the example you gave, the label column was created from concatinating the whole dataframe columns. `duplicate` does exactly that. it concatenates all the columns together, and therefore, there was no need of creating it

Comment: Thanks . I corrected the  code to show I am not labeling the whole row. Apologies. as using the whole row was not my intent... just what I accidentally did in making my example.

Comment: @KirstenGreed just subset accordingly ie `duplicated(iris[c('Species', 'Petal.Length')])` etc. or even just use `duplicated(df$label)` please check the comment made by thelatemail